# How to know what an object porperty does

Tags: powershell

I needed to get an overview of users from a certain **OU**. However, when i get-member, i receive multiple properties with "*name*" in it. With trying i finally found out which 1 i needed. But i assume there is a faster way to understand what each property actually stands for / does.

```
'''
   TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser

Name              MemberType Definition                                                                                                                         
----              ---------- ----------                                                                                                                         
DistinguishedName Property   System.String DistinguishedName {get;set;}                                                                                         
Enabled           Property   System.Boolean Enabled {get;set;}                                                                                                  
GivenName         Property   System.String GivenName {get;set;}                                                                                                 
Name              Property   System.String Name {get;}                                                                                                          
ObjectClass       Property   System.String ObjectClass {get;set;}                                                                                               
ObjectGUID        Property   System.Nullable`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] ObjectGUID {get;set;}
SamAccountName    Property   System.String SamAccountName {get;set;}                                                                                            
SID               Property   System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier SID {get;set;}                                                                        
Surname           Property   System.String Surname {get;set;}                                                                                                   
UserPrincipalName Property   System.String UserPrincipalName {get;set;}          
'''
```

Comment: I know i can google it, was just wondering if their would be any help-cmdlet thingy for standard stuff like get-help get-aduser.surname or something like that. Beginner here so yeah...

Comment: enter `get-help get-aduser -full` for the cmdlet. Some stuff has an about (
`help about_operators`). But the properties of objects are only documented online AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general entering the TypeName (`[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser]`) in your favorite search engine, will show you a fitting Microsoft site, which lists all properties. However how well those documentations are written differs greatly. Sometimes a quick glance will tell you all you need to know (eg. `[system.windows.forms.form]`), sometimes it's completly useless like in your case.